# Customize Video Before Streaming

Tags: java, video, video-streaming, video-processing

I have encountered a very strange situation.
I want to Customize Video by applying filters on it ,
Like if i want to Add Some Text or Lighting on the video and then stream it.

So what approach do i take

> Get Raw VIDEO --> Compress --> Modify --> Encode Using H.264 -->
>   Stream

or

> Get Raw VIDEO --> Modify --> Compress --> Encode Using H.264 -->
>   Stream

I am using Java and some natives in my project.

Currently i can video call but not able to Modify Video.

## Update 1

What did i ask wrong , someone down vote this question , may i know why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No Idea someone down-voted you :( Yours is a valid question...

To answer, it depends on how you want the effects to be applied... If you have the time to apply effects, compress and stream (well, its not "LIVE", there is a time gap during the process), the method you described works well.

But if your requirements require you to apply the filters or text or effects on the fly while capturing and broadcasting (The usual thing you do when you broadcast a live event), you cannot use the above mentioned method. You will have to use a hardware capture card, which does all the encoding and appliying filters on the hardware side, sothat there is not a "delay"...

The below card is a starting point.
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/598248-REG/Blackmagic_Design_BDLKSDI_DeckLink_SDI_PCI_Express.html

complete range of products.
http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/in/products/decklink

choose whichone fits your budget. Once you have the card, you can use the software which ships with your card or any third party tool to apply filters.

If you want even a custom tailored solution, you can use the video stream from the card and manipulate it on the fly with C++/C# API libraries available from http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/sdks/

Even better SDK's there from thirdparties.
http://www.medialooks.com/mplatform/

Hope this helps,
Aby

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer , but is there any possibility in software , i can give you a link where they implemented this in software at basic level , refer http://manycam.com/ , please guide me on it .

Comment: @Mihir, Yes I've evaluated ManyCam before, it is good as long as your broadcast quality is low and screen size does not exceed 320x480. If you try to do it with higher bitrate video, the broadcasted video will look pixelated.

What manycam does is, install a virtual videocam, you use their virtual camera for your broadcasting purposes. Its good for 'amateur' useses, but not broadcast quality. You can try their free trial and see if it fits your requirements.

Comment: yes i can limit the screen size to this one and i can adjust quality but my sole purpose is to achieve this in software , now can you guide me on that ?